# Connecting to an instance of mysql on was from java client application

Tags: java, mysql, ssl, amazon-web-services

I have been searching for hours on the internet and can't seem to find a step by step tutorial for what I want. I am writing a java desktop application that connects to an instance of a mysql database on amazon web services. This works fine. Now I want to change the connection so that it is SSL. According to the aws web site, each DB instance has a certificate installed on it. the public key is available at https://rds.amazonaws.com/doc/mysql-ssl-ca-cert.pem . I know that I need to modify the connection url in my java program to include the properties useSSL and requireSSL and set them to true. I have downloaded the was public key and set the above two properties. What do I do next? Do I need a certificate signed by a trusted authority or is that the certificate which is already installed on the was DB instance? How do I use the downloaded public key in my program? What steps do I need to follow? I would appreciate step by step instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much searching I was finally able to find a solution thanks to this link http://forums.visokio.com/discussion/2651/data-sources-connecting-to-amazon-rds-database-mysql-using-ssl . First i downloaded the public key from the aws RD site. Then I navigated to the ire/library/securit folder and copied the file called carets into the same directory as the downloaded pen file. Then I ran the following command:

```
keytool -import -alias mysqlServerCACert -file mysql-ssl-ca-cert.pem -keystore cacerts
```

I then specified that I want to trust this certificate and entered the password (which was "change it"). I then copied the cacerts file into a folder (called cert) in my Java application and used the following commands before getting the connection to the database:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","cert/cacerts");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","changeit");
```

And everything worked perfectly fine for me.